# Display MYSQL Data From a Menu

Tags: php, mysql, database, menu

I have a MYSQL database with a number of fields such as property, bedrooms, size etc

I have two dropdown list with data that is contained within the database

When submitting the options I want a new page to open displaying the results.  I am getting the error message mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL and have no idea how to fix this! help much appreciated...I know about SQL injections and looking to rectify this after I get this section working first

HTML

```
     <form method="get" action="submit.php">

     Number:  <select name="property">
     <option value="Aviemore House">Aviemore House</option>
     <option value="Dalfaber House">Dalfaber House</option>
     </select>
     <br>

     Name: <select name="bedrooms">
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option></select>
     <br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

PHP

```
 <?php

 require 'defaults.php';
 require 'database.php';


 $property = $_GET['property'] ;
 $bedrooms = $_GET['bedrooms'] ;

 $query = "select FROM properties where property = '$property' & bedrooms = '$bedrooms'";

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$r[] = $row;
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute your query!

```
<?php

 require 'defaults.php';
 require 'database.php';


 $property = $_GET['property'] ;
 $bedrooms = $_GET['bedrooms'] ;

 $query = "select FROM properties where property = '$property' & bedrooms = '$bedrooms'";
 $result = mysql_query($query); // <-- You forgot this
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    $r[] = $row;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Yours still wouldn't work due to SQL query being malformatted, though. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE property = '{$property}' AND bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}'";
$row=mysql_query($query);
```

Your sql is malformatted and need to execute the query.

Comment: thats for that I got it working..if I want to use more than 2 variables, I have $property and $bedrooms at the moment do I use the AND statement if I want to you say 4 other variables (such as $sleep_min and $price)

Comment: Just add more statements like `AND sleep='{$sleep_min}' AND... etc` Upvotes and marking the answer correct is important, remember :)

Comment: Guess it should be `$result=mysql_query($query);` to work with your loop. Mark answers as the answer if given.