# Display Data From MYSQL; SQL statement error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a form..want to display the data from mysql table..problem is that the SQL query statement is not displaying the data..any ideas? I think the error may be orruring due to the AND statement in the SQL query line?

```
  <form method="get" action="submit.php">

   Number of Bedrooms: <select name="bedrooms">
   <option selected value='#'>--Choose Number of Bedrooms--</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>


   Number of Occupants:  <select name="sleeps_min">
   <option selected value='#'>--Choose Number of Bedrooms--</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>  
   <option value="10">10</option>
   </select>

   Availability:  <select name="availability">
   <option selected value='#'>--Select Availability Period--</option>
   <option value="All year round">All Year Round</option>
   <option value="New Year Availability Only">New Year</option>

   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

--

```
 require 'defaults.php';
 require 'database.php';

 /* get properties from database */

 $property = $_GET['bedrooms'] ;
 $sleeps_min = $_GET['sleeps_min'] ;
 $availability = $_GET['availability'] ;


  $query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}' sleeps_min = '{$sleeps_min}' AND availability = '{$availability}'";
  $row=mysql_query($query);

  $result = do_query("SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}' sleeps_min = '{$sleeps_min}' AND availability = '{$availability}'", $db_connection);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$r[] = $row;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326077/display-mysql-data-from-a-menu, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326077/display-mysql-data-from-a-menu

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a logical operator (e.g. `AND`) in your where clause:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}' sleeps_min =
                                                                   ^----here
```

and your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. At bare minimum you should be passing your $_GET variables through [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

If you had even bare-bones error handling in your code, you'd have seen the syntax error:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**NEVER** assume a query succeeded. Even if the SQL syntax itself is perfect (yours isn't), there's far too may other reasons for queries to fail to NOT check for failure.

Comment: cheer that works! do you know a way to display text like "no records found" when no database criteria is met after submitting the form..eg there is no accommodation with 6 bedrooms and accupys 10 people so an error message will appear?

Comment: @Dave `if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { // show no records found message }`

Comment: where abouts would I insert that? sorry for being a pain!!