# MYSQL Results; no records found statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display Data From MYSQL; SQL statement error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326746/display-data-from-mysql-sql-statement-error)

I have the code below displaying data from a MYSQL database (currently looking into sql injection issue) I need to insert an error message when no results are found...not sure where to position this! I have tried the code if( mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo "No row found!" but keep on gettin syntax errors, does anyone know the correct position in the code for this?

--

```
 require 'defaults.php';
 require 'database.php';

 /* get properties from database */

 $property = $_GET['bedrooms'] ;
 $sleeps_min = $_GET['sleeps_min'] ;
 $availability = $_GET['availability'] ;


  $query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}' AND sleeps_min = '{$sleeps_min}' AND availability = '{$availability}'";
  $row=mysql_query($query);

  $result = do_query("SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}' sleeps_min = '{$sleeps_min}' AND availability = '{$availability}'", $db_connection);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$r[] = $row;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: no different question cheers for the minus

Comment: ths minus for the posting the code in the form of the wordy description. It is hard as hell to find a PHP syntax error in the code "I have tried the code but keep on gettin syntax errors"

Comment: no syntax error but all i want to know is where i the code i put the statement...$row = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Dave, you're not evening finishing your other questions. And where do you define your `do_query()` function? `$row` is being overwritten and `$result` isn't defined anywhere that would actually work as far as I can tell. Learn to use Stack before expecting help. Hell, learn basic PHP before that.

Comment: `but keep on gettin syntax errors` - this is your own words. You have to make your mind first than come to ask questions

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326077/display-mysql-data-from-a-menu, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326746/display-data-from-mysql-sql-statement-error

Comment: @Dave: so mr.king why dont you solve your own question then?

Comment: @ShashankKadne, He has no clue, even when you answer his 4 duplicate questions. Making up your own functions without defining them is very.. kingish?

Comment: just joking around pal, why so serious?

Comment: @Dave Because this is a Q & A site, not a joke forum. Might want to head over to /b/.

Comment: One issue i found in query that there is no variable `$bedrooms` in ` bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}'` here you have to use `$property` Please try this

Answer (score 0):

Do `var_dump($GET_)` to debug whether you are getting valid strings. If any of these are blank, the query will try to match blank values instead of `NULL`. You should prevent this by doing:

```
if(!$_GET['bedrooms'] || $_GET['bedrooms'] == ''){
$property = 'NULL';
}//repeat for all three

$query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE 'bedrooms' = '$bedrooms' AND 'sleeps_min' = '$sleeps_min' AND 'availability' = '$availability'";
```

Instead of:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $r[] = $row; 
}
```

You can simply do:

```
$r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

But enclose that in a conditional to see if your query found anything:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
  //your code here will execute when there is at least one result
  $r = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
} 
else{//There was either nothing or an error
  if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0){
    //There were 0 results 
  } 
  if(mysql_affected_rows() == -1) {
    //This executes when there is an error 
    print mysql_error(); //not recommended except to debug
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like using `if( !empty( $_GET['bedrooms'] ) ) { }` would be a simpler conditional.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found few errors in your code that  in line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}' AND sleeps_min = '{$sleeps_min}' AND availability = '{$availability}'";
$row=mysql_query($query);
```

You use `bedrooms = '{$bedrooms}'` but `$bedrooms is not variable in whole cod it must be $preopery`. I have made a few changes in your code given below please try it.

```
        <?php

        require 'defaults.php';
        require 'database.php';

        /* get properties from database */

        /*if get $_GET['bedrooms'] value else ''*/

        if (isset($_GET['bedrooms'])) {
            $property = $_GET['bedrooms'];
        } else {
            $property = '';
        }

        /*if get $_GET['sleeps_min'] value else ''*/

        if (isset($_GET['sleeps_min'])) {
            $sleeps_min = $_GET['sleeps_min'];
        } else {
            $sleeps_min = '';
        }

        /*if get $_GET['availability'] value else ''*/

        if (isset($_GET['availability'])) {
            $availability = $_GET['availability'];
        } else {
            $availability = '';
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE bedrooms = '" . $property . "' AND sleeps_min = '" . $sleeps_min . "' AND availability = '" . $availability . "'";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        if ($result) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $r[] = $row;
            }
        }
        ?>
```